# Renaming Rails database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql

I created an app called food-pantry-manager - I found that the dashes create problems with postgresql which apparently doesn't like dashes - I tried renaming the database to just pantry but I am worried about problems popping up with the inconsistent naming

Should I not worry about this?

make some changes to resolve the name issue?

Rename my app to pantry like my database - This isn't easy from what I've seen?

Thanks

Tom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no problem with naming a database `food-pantry-manager`, you just have to double quote the identifier when you use it so that the hyphens arent' misinterpreted; for example:

```
psql => create database "where-is-pancakes-house?";
```

That said, you'll have a better time if all your PostgreSQL identifiers (database names, column names, table names, ...) are lower case alphanumeric with underscores to separate words. That way you don't have to worry about quoting your identifiers or case issues or similar irritations.

As far as Rails is concerned, it doesn't care what the database name is, it just reads the database name out of `database.yml` and uses it. So you could call your database `fargo` if you wanted and set up your `database.yml` like this:

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  database: fargo
  ...
```

and everything should be happy regardless of what your application is called.

Comment: Thanks I was just concerned that the rails convention over configuration thing would make my life tough with different names